# Node.js Kafka : Batching Multiple Messages

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Today I noticed that it is written as below in under High Level Producer of kafka-node.

⚠️WARNING: Batch multiple messages of the same topic/partition together as an array on the messages attribute otherwise you may lose messages!

What does it mean ? Is it means that messages may get lost if I frequently tries to write data to same topic/partition without batch ?